# Service Is Looping In Crazy Way

Tags: android

I've just made a service to set something, Added a log and a timer, the timer delay is taken form sharedpreferences value, the value is returning 5 minutes, the problem that the Service is looping in a crazy way, it's not a 1 sec delay, nope .. it's less than a second delay and it's outputting the log message .

And to mention, I'm using the same code with another service, I have this problem only in this service, Codes :

Manifest :

```
        <service
        android:name=".services.ServiceTest"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

Switch that starts the service :

```
            Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),ReceiverTest.class);
                BroadcastIntent.setAction(packagetest+"startservice");
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
```

Receiver takes the action, in a if statement and runs the service via intent in the following way :

```
        Intent ServiceTestIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class);
        context.startService(ServiceTestIntent);
```

The Service :

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    SharedPreferences Preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int Delay= Preference.getInt("Value", 2 * 60 * 1000);
    MyTimer = new Timer();
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {
            MyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(Fragment.TAG,"Message Test");
                }
            }, Delay, Delay);
        }
    }.start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

The delay returns 5 minutes (5*60*1000) and then i store it in the sharedpreferences, When i log the value it says 5 minutes, so it's a correct time, even though the default is 2 minutes, the service loops directly and output the message .

Receiver :

```
        if(intent.getAction().equals(mainactivity.package+"startservice"))
    {
        context.startService(ServiceIntent);
    }
```

UPDATE : 
Another thing is, I got 3 other services with different receivers, When i switch any of them, the Test service will be launched, even though i didn't start it or reference it, or anything related to it in the other switches .
I've tried rebooting/App full deletion using Root App remover .

Comment: Are you sure that the Delay value is in the correct units?  should be in milliseconds, so the actual value should be 300000.  I see it's right in your default return value in `Preference.getInt()`, but I'm asking about what's stored in your preference file.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, What i typed is just a note, So no one get me wrong, But seems someone got me wrong :p .

Comment: just checking - "code never lies, comments sometimes do".  -- not calling you a liar, just saying everyone makes mistakes.  :)

Comment: Np, the value is 300000, it's returning right, Gonna try to build it again and review everything i add and see .

Comment: can you post your broadcast receiver code?  If you are receiving other events and starting other services, you may be starting this one at the same time by accident, as your UPDATE indicates.

Comment: Posted it, the problem is solved, check my comment below .

Answer (score 0):

Add a log statement to show the delay.  Either the delay value is wrong or the service is being started multiple times:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    SharedPreferences Preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final int Delay= Preference.getInt("Value", 2 * 60 * 1000);
    Log.i(Fragment.TAG, String.format("onStartCommand(): delay=%d", Delay));
    final Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {
            MyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(Fragment.TAG, "Message Test");
                }
            }, Delay, Delay);
        }
    }.start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: The value is correct, which is "300000", Gonna re-build it again and review everything i add.

Comment: When you viewed this log output, did you see the first log statement `Log.i(Fragment.TAG, String.format("onStartCommand(): delay=%d", Delay));` printed only once, and then the second one printed many times?  Or both printed many times?

Comment: The "onStartCommand()..." message will appear once for each time `startService()` is called for your service.  When I ran this code, it appeared once and then the "Message Test" message appeared every `Delay` milliseconds.  If you see "onStartCommand()..."  multiple times, your service is being started multiple times, with a new timer thread for each.

Comment: Well it appears a lot :D, I've just coded the class again from scratch, and the problem is solved, And i'm feeling crazy because I re-wrote the same codes, but after trying the log, the message outputted only once.